# not working IE8 if option value selected switch css

Tags: jquery, animation

I know there is probably a better way of doing this, I have tried many ways. I would normally do the `.hide()` or `.show()` but the css display switch has been working better on FF, not on IE. Here is my code

```
$(".VariationSelect option[value='21']").click(function () {
    $("#21").css("display", "block");
});
$(".VariationSelect option[value!='21']").click(function () {
    $("#21").css("display", "none");
});
```

I've tried case switch and if and else but nothing works

```
<div class="Value">
    <select name="variation[1]" class="VariationSelect" style="width: 180px;">
        <option value="">Choose a Ring Size</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="21">Custom</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="21" style="margin-left:20px; float:left; display:none"> 
    <div class="Label" style="margin-top:5px; ">
        Custom Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the click function called when you click on the "option" in IE? My guess is click events aren't triggered on option elements in IE. Put a change(..) on the select instead and test the value.

Here is the code:

```
    $(".VariationSelect").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "21") {
        $("#21").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $("#21").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I wouldn't recommend using IDs and classes that start with a number.

**jQuery**

```
$(".VariationSelect").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '21') {
        $("#cont_21").show();
    } else {
        $("#cont_21").hide();
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="cont_21" style="margin-left:20px; float:left; display:none"> 
    <div class="Label" style="margin-top:5px; ">
        Custom Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/QChsD/).

Hope this helps !

Comment: Sorry for the near-duplicate answer. When I started writing it, there was no code posted :)

Comment: Im always amazed how quick people respond to questions. So many times by the time I am done writing a response someone else has already answered it. :-)

Comment: @Plaudit Indeed, that happens a lot :)